# Language-Agnostic way to mathematically determine HexBin of (N) size center coordinate, given Lat, Long input

Tags: javascript, python, function, math, hex

I have latitude and longitude coordinates.

```
 -76.054657667, 36.818969167
```

Is there a simple function that will translate these to a fall into the center of a hexagon (in lat/long coordinates) of whatever size within a tesselating hexagon map (units can be arbitrary, say meters if you have to)?

I understand it can ambiguous because in Uber h3 or the d3 hex model whatever, there can be variance in where one hexagon starts and ends depending on your global map. I'm looking for a vastly simplified model here.

For instance, for basic square coordinates, a simple rounding function could work on both long and lat. If you round longitude and latitude to 2 decimal places for instance, you can 'bin' them into squares of a constant size.

I'm trying to simply bin them into hexagonal shapes, but using a a vastly simplified function for now.

Perhaps this sort of simplification is not possible, but curious. Thanks!